# how to load image in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make image viewer which have functionality of **`rotate and zoom in and zoom out`**So I take canvas to draw image , but I think it is not working then I straight way i added my `image` src url (I know this is not good approach) .I need to draw image using canvas so that I can rotate and zoom my image.
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/6z651o698n

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      src:
        "https://img.timesnownews.com/story/1542606525-Sachin_Shaw.png?d=600x450"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("d");

    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var image = document.getElementById("image");
  }

  resetImage() {
    //load the  image in canvas if the image is loaded successfully
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const image = document.getElementById("image");
    const element = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const currentScale = Math.min(
      canvas.width / image.width,
      canvas.height / image.height
    );
  }
  clear() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const element = canvas.getContext("2d");
    element.clearRect(-2000, -2000, 5000, 5000);
  }
  drawImage() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const element = canvas.getContext("2d");
    clear();
    element.save();
    element.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    element.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);
    element.drawImage(
      image,
      canvas.width / 2 / currentScale - image.width / 2,
      canvas.height / 2 / currentScale - image.height / 2
    );
    element.restore();
  }
  zoomIn() {
    currentScale += 0.5;
    drawImage();
  }

  zoomIn() {
    currentScale -= 0.5;
    drawImage();
  }

  render() {
    console.log("r");
    return (
      <div>
        <button id="zoomIn" onClick={this.zoomIn}>
          {" "}
          Zoom In
        </button>
        <button id="zoomIn" onClick={this.zoomOut}>
          {" "}
          Zoom In
        </button>

        <canvas id="canvas" height="350" data-girar="0">
          sdsd
        </canvas>
        <img id="image" src={this.state.src} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**may be I did lot of mistake here because I am new in react ** currently `zoom in and zoom out functionality not working`

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of work to be done, but you can start from the following steps:

1. All calls to methods must start with `this.`, so replace `clear()` and `drawImage()` with `this.clear()` and `this.drawImage()`.
2. In order for variable `currentScale` to persist, you can make it global, object property, or part of react state. I suggest to start with object property, so replace all occurrences of `currentScale` with `this.currentScale`. In order to initialize this property, you have to call `this.resetImage()` in `componentDidMount`.
3. When you pass callbacks like in `onClick={this.zoomIn}`, you have to bind them to `this`. There are several ways to do this, the simpliest is to replace it with `onClick={this.zoomIn.bind(this)}`

There are several small typos: you have two `zoomIn` methods and do not have `const image` declaration in `drawImage`.